# Improve sql query in MySQL in PHPMYADMIN

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have this query:

```
SELECT  `jos_eb_registrants`. * ,  `jos_eb_field_values`. * 
FROM jos_eb_registrants, jos_eb_field_values
WHERE  `jos_eb_registrants`.`event_id` =3
AND  `jos_eb_registrants`.`id` =  `jos_eb_field_values`.`registrant_id`
```

It returns me everything from these two tables, but gives me rows with duplicate names, because ONE name from first table can have more than one field value. How to make field values not in separate rows, but in one row near one name, without duplicates. Please edit this query with my variables.**Tables connected via Id and registrant_id.**

```
jos_eb_field_values

1   id   
2   registrant_id    
3   field_id     
4   field_value
```

```
jos_eb_registrants 
     1  id  
     2  event_id
     3  user_id      
     4  group_id    
     5  first_name       
     6  last_name            
     7  organization         
     8  address 
     9  address2         
     10 city             
     11 state        
     12 country      
     13 zip      
     14 phone    
     15 fax      
     16 email            
     17 number_registrants       
     18 total_amount         
     19 discount_amount          
     20 amount  
     21 register_date            
     22 payment_date         
     23 payment_method       
     24 transaction_id       
     25 comment text    
     26 published            
     27 cart_id int(11)              
     28 deposit_amount       
     29 payment_status       
     30 coupon_id   
     31 check_coupon         
     32 tax_amount           
     33 registration_code        
     34 is_reminder_sent         
     35 is_group_billing
```

Comment: You're select all columns. There cannot be duplicates across ALL columns!

Comment: no, i get name fieldvalue1
          name fieldvalue2 etc.

I need name fieldvalue1 fieldvalue2

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

SELECT DISTINCT `jos_eb_registrants`. * ,  `jos_eb_field_values`. * 
FROM jos_eb_registrants
INNER JOIN jos_eb_field_values ON `jos_eb_registrants`.`id` = `jos_eb_field_values`.`registrant_id`
WHERE  `jos_eb_registrants`.`event_id` =3

Comment: DISTINCT across ALL columns is nonsensical.

Comment: This query gives no results. Still the same result.